# background-color of div doesn't filling to 100% of it's width. 1px of div is kinda not filling

Tags: html, css

Very silly question, but i can't understand...
In a row of small div elements some of my divs have different margin-right, even if i define same margin-right for all row items. I wonder what exactly fires this kind of action.

P.S. Thanks for reading, sorry for my bad english

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
}
.row__item{
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="row__item"></div>
  <div class="row__item"></div>
  <div class="row__item"></div>
  <div class="row__item"></div>
  <div class="row__item"></div>
  <div class="row__item"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: sometimes its the animation, sometimes its the unclosed div, unknown extra div or same class with different margin or an extra div. It can be anything. your code alone works fine. whats your browser? inspect your site and see each of your div. Another thing is you have margin right so that will give 1px space on the right thats why it doesnt fill 100%.

Comment: Are you seeing it changing with zooming in or out?

Comment: I suspect what you are seeing is a sort of rounding error phenomenon - the system is having to work out how many screen pixels to use (there are several per CSS pixel on modern screens) and sometimes an extra screen pixel can get 'left behind' so in your example a margin can seem wider than its neighbours not wider by one whole CSS pixel but by one screen pixel.

Comment: A Haworth - no, it's still the same

Comment: @colainmyvein please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

`margin` is outside of element that's so normal for it to Not take background

Remove `margin-right` to get rid of that space

If you want your content to be spaced from each other and yet take the background, use padding instead

Padding box is a part of your element (breathing space between content-box and border-box)

And if you want the padding Not to add up with your element's (50px) width, the answer is `box-sizing: border-box;`

So if this wasn't what you mean and what you need, let me know

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
}
.row__item{
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="row__item"></div>
  <div class="row__item"></div>
  <div class="row__item"></div>
  <div class="row__item"></div>
  <div class="row__item"></div>
  <div class="row__item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @segFault Ok i didn't get what you said, my English is not good and even Google translator couldn't help me to get what you said, can you clarify what you mean?    :|